# Local iis user authentication with custom credential drops unauthorized

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, basic-authentication

We have a quite old IIS 6.5 running on a Windows Server 2012 R2. I have a WCF service (.net 4.8), and I want to create a client which connects to this service.

I added a **local IIS user** (not a local user!) to the IIS itself, and in the service web.config I allowed this user to authorize. The WCF app uses **Basic** + **Windows** authentication.

```
<authorization>
 <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
 <add accessType="Allow" users="webtest_local_iis_user" />                
</authorization>
```

I tried to construct the custom credential in several ways ...

```
var customCredential = new NetworkCredential("webtest_local_iis_user","myPwd123","webtest")
var customCredential = new NetworkCredential("webtest\\webtest_local_iis_user","myPwd123")
var customCredential = new NetworkCredential("localhost\\webtest_local_iis_user","myPwd123")
var customCredential = new NetworkCredential(".\\webtest_local_iis_user","myPwd123")
```

... and using it in constructing WCF service client like this:

```
var result = new DownloadServiceClient();
((ClientBase<IDownloadService>)result).ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = customCredential.UserName;
((ClientBase<IDownloadService>)result).ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = customCredential.Password;
((ClientBase<IDownloadService>)result).ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = customCredential;
```

But at the end I always got an error:

```
MessageSecurityException: 'The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM,Basic realm="webtest"'.'

WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

Why is that? How can I connect to this service? Is it a problem constructing the credentials?

Comment: Btw in the iis log the user cannot be seen: 2022-01-31 10:58:06 192.168.21.22 POST /Download/DownloadService.svc/DOWNLOAD - 443 - 10.20.2.16 - - 401 2 5 15

Comment: Basic or Windows authentication only accepts user credentials of local Windows accounts or Active Directory accounts. So from the very beginning you were on the wrong direction.

Comment: Woo thats's brand new to me. What is Local IIS account is good for - if cannot log in using this credential?

Comment: Those so called IIS Manager Users as only recognized by IIS Manager, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh831549(v=ws.11)#add-user-and-change-password-dialog-boxes